# How to use the Spotify class in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay so I am writing a command which just shows some info about what song a user is listening to, for example `k!spotify @user` shows the song name, artist, album, album cover etc etc. However, I am having issues with the Spotify class.

This is my first time trying to use the Spotify class, but I don't think that's the problem. I would like these variables to be user-specific and not `<property object at 0x0460B7E0>`:

```py
async def spotify(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    if not user:
        user = ctx.message.author.id
    else:
        user = user.id

    sname = discord.Spotify.title
    sartists = discord.Spotify.artists
    album = discord.Spotify.album
    palbum = discord.Spotify.album_cover_url
    duration = discord.Spotify.duration
```

I am aware that `discord.Spotify.title` etc won't give me something user-specific, but I tried `user.Spotify.title` and things along those lines to no avail. I am sure this is just a misunderstanding from me, but how should I use the spotify class here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Spotify`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Spotify) is a type of [`Activity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Activity). You need to get [`Member.activities`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.activities) and select only the ones that are also `Spotify`. I don't know if it's possible to have more than one of a particular activity, so you might have to account for that:

```
from discord import Spotify

@bot.command()
async def spotify(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    user = user or ctx.author
    for activity in user.activities:
        if isinstance(activity, Spotify):
            await ctx.send(f"{user} is listening to {activity.title} by {activity.artist}")
```

Comment: in the line `if isinstance(activity, Spotify)` i get: `NameError: name 'Spotify' is not defined`?

Comment: you need to import it `from discord import Spotify`

Comment: Oh, I tried `from discord.ext.commands import Spotify` then stopped trying, haha, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
from discord import Spotify

@bot.command()
async def spotify(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
        pass
    if user.activities:
        for activity in user.activities:
            if isinstance(activity, Spotify):
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title = f"{user.name}'s Spotify",
                    description = "Listening to {}".format(activity.title),
                    color = 0xC902FF)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=activity.album_cover_url)
                embed.add_field(name="Artist", value=activity.artist)
                embed.add_field(name="Album", value=activity.album)
                embed.set_footer(text="Song started at {}".format(activity.created_at.strftime("%H:%M")))
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```